# javascript HAML partial response for Rails AJAX not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using HAML to return js for `remote:true` form

Below is my code:

```
$('#chat-message').val('');
$('ul.chat').append('#{j render(@chat)}');
```

This line seems to create an error and does not parse correctly.

When I delete the second line it works fine with first line.

What could be wrong?

Below is the error:

````
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /chats
=====================================

> Missing partial chats/chat with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-4/projects/virtual_exhibition/app/views"
  * "C:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-4/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jasmine-rails-0.4.9/app/views"
  * "C:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-4/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/bigbluebutton_rails-2c99a8402df4/app/views"
  * "C:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-4/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise_invitable-1.3.1/app/views"
  * "C:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-4/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.1/app/views"


app/views/chats/create.html.haml, line 2
----------------------------------------

``` ruby
    1   $('#chat-message').val('');
>   2   $('ul.chat').append("#{j render(@chat)}");
````

Comment: Do you have a demo of this or more code you can share?

Comment: @notrab just updated with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes `"` not single quotes `'` for expression inside `#{j render(@chat)}` to be evaluated:

```
$('ul.chat').append("#{j render(@chat)}");
```

Comment: I've just updated with my question. I have double quotes now but still same error. Could I be missing a partial

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper, when you render an object like `render @chat`, you also need a view by the name `_chat.html.haml` in this case.

Comment: damn doublequotes! How did I not see that? Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get string interpolation you need " ", not ' '

So do:

```
"#{j render(@chat)}"
```

Comment: do you have a partial named `chats/chat` ? what partial would you like to render?

Comment: Sorry you are right I just added `_chat.html.haml` and it worked. Thanks!